# Confusing lsb_release output, mismatched versions

Tags: 20.04, package-management, 21.04, lsb-release

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    20.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

As far as I remember I didn't tamper with any configuration files. I checked /etc/lsb-release and it is fine

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=hirsute
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.04"
```

Where else can this 20.04 come from and how to fix it? I am trying to install something with a script that automaticaly choses the python version based on the output of lsb_release and it is failing because of that.

Comment: The command `find /etc/*release` finds also `/etc/os-release`. What's the content in that file? Is your system release-upgraded with `do-release-upgrade`?